# IntellIJ Remove % Methods and Lines Covered in Project Files Window

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I remove "% methods and % lines covered in IntelliJ Window? I might have accidentally pressed a view window. Trying to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could close the "Coverage" tool window which should remove these coverage numbers too.

[image]

Comment: I have the latest intellij, I dont see that option, how can I get to Coverage window removal from windows menu in intellij instead of icon?

Comment: Try clicking the IDEA main menu `View | Tool Windows |  Coverage` to show the Coverage tool window, and close the X icon in the Coverage tool window tab, does it help?